# How find this integral $\;\int\frac{\sqrt{\ln{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})}}}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Find the integral

$$I=\int\dfrac{\sqrt{\ln{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})}}}{1+x^2}dx$$

My try: let
$$x=\tan{t}$$
$$I=\int\sqrt{\ln{(\tan{t}+\sec{t})}}dt$$
note
$$\tan{t}+\sec{t}=\dfrac{\sin{t}}{\cos{t}}+\dfrac{1}{\cos{t}}=\dfrac{\sin{\dfrac{t}{2}}+\cos{\dfrac{t}{2}}}{\cos{\dfrac{t}{2}}-\sin{\dfrac{t}{2}}}=\tan{\left(\dfrac{t}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)}$$then I can't,Thank you

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613674/a-question-on-integration/613680

Comment: [WA declares there is no result to be found in standard functions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+%28\sqrt%28ln%28x%2B\sqrt%28x^2%2B1%29%29%29%29%2F%281%2Bx^2%29+dx%29)

Comment: Looks like a job for [commissioner Gordon](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/53268/ron-gordon).

Comment: Use the substitution $x=\sinh(u)$. This will give you $$\int\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\cosh^2(u)}\text{d}u.$$ Then go from there... good !

Comment: It may be that the integral does not have a closed form. You may find Liouville's integral theorem useful in proving this...

Comment: I feel bad about voting to close this question as a duplicate of a closed question.  Thus, I am nominating the other one for reopening...  (requesting votes...)

Comment: @anorton If you regard questions without motivation as close-worthy, you should answer this one and not the other one.

Comment: @Phira I have reconsidered.  Close vote retracted.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian

Its related too the Gudermannian !